# Split String by delimiter in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wrote a split by delimiter function in Haskell and wanted some feedback on this piece of code.
Since I come from an imperative programming background, I often write too complex functions in haskell.

```
split :: Char -> String -> [String]
split c str = fst $ splitInternal c ([], str)

splitInternal :: Char -> ([String], String) -> ([String], String)
splitInternal _ (result, "")  = (result, "")
splitInternal c (result, str) = splitInternal c (
    result ++ [takeWhile (/= c) str], 
    case dropWhile (/= c) str of
        "" -> ""
        rest -> tail rest
    )
```

My questions are

1. Is it bad to have splitInternal function? I couldn't figure out a way without it.
2. Is there maybe a simpler way to write the function?
3. Any other feedback is welcome as well

Answer (score 4):

> Is it bad to have splitInternal function? I couldn't figure out a way without it.

Well, according to your procedure, I think it is necessary, but you can improve the readibility by writing some small functions and then combining them together. Besides, if there are consecutive delimiters, your `split` function doesn't work as expected. The code can be rewritten as following:

```hs
splitInternal :: Char -> ([String], String) -> ([String], String)
splitInternal _ (result, "") = (result, "")
splitInternal c (result, remain) = splitInternal c (getBefore c remain, getAfter c remain)
  where
    getBefore delimiter rest = result ++ [takeWhile (/= delimiter) rest]
    getAfter delimiter rest = dropWhile (== delimiter) . dropWhile (/= delimiter) $ rest
```

> Is there maybe a simpler way to write the function?

Yes, you can use the `break` and `span` function defined in `Prelude`:

```hs
split :: Char -> String -> [String]
split _ "" = []
split delimiter str = 
    let (start, rest) = break (== delimiter) str
        (_, remain) = span (== delimiter) rest
     in start : split delimiter remain
```

So in this case, your `splitInternal` is unnecessary.

> Any other feedback is welcome as well

Well, if you are dealing with string, then a better choice is `Text` from `Data.Text`. `Text` is more efficient than `String` when you are dealing with string. In the module `Data.Text`, there is a pre-defined function `splitOn` that works almost as you expect:

````hs
ghci> :seti -XOverloadedString

ghci> splitOn "," "123,456,789"
["123","456","789"]

ghci> splitOn "," "123,,,456,789"
["123","","","456","789"]           -- This is what I mean "almost", since splitOn doesn't use the consecutive delimiters. Maybe this is what you want.
```
````